# XSL/XML v1.0 Parsing in Edge. Is it possible to ignore control characters? (here: explicitly SOH/ETX) (IE works, Edge doesn't)

Tags: xml, xslt, cross-browser, xslt-1.0, control-characters

I have some issues with several XML Files that (unfortunately, against the specs) have control characters embedded, such as ETX or SOH.

I can't manipulate the files as I don't have access to the server.
My company uses IE11* to show these XML files via XSL-Stylesheets and they work fine there.
However when tried to view the files in EDGE** (as we plan to move forward and use this instead) they would not show at all.
Console says "*Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml*"
This is caused by the aforementioned control characters.

For example, the following XML will be visible fine in IE11*, but not on Edge and not on FFX (which I used for simple test/comparison):

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head> <title> <xsl:value-of select="root/@title"/> </title> 
        <meta   http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8'/> </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="root/mydata/text()"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' standalone='yes'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xml' href='../../stylesheet/soh.xsl'?>
<root title="XSL SOH Test">
<mydata> Data with SOH  </mydata>
</root>
```

The XML file is opened via web browser, calling "127.0.0.1:8080/data/soh.xml".
It is hosted on a PHP developer system run via cmd "php.exe -S "

Is there any way to ignore these Just like the IE11* seems to ignore them? (or is there a setting in the EDGE/IE11 I have to adjust?)

What I tried:

- XSL Output method "html", "text" and "xml"
- XSL transform() on the elements containing SOH
- XSL encapsulated affected elements in try/catch blocks
- XSL disable-output-escaping="yes" on elements containing SOH
- XML stylesheet-type "text/xsl", "text/xml", "application/xml"

I know that these characters are not allowed for XML (version 1.0), however I am confused as to why the IE11* is correctly showing the data, while EDGE and FFX can't. (I guess, because IE was more relaxed when it came to these things..)

If there is no way to fix this, could you provide a way to at least show an error message, like shown in FFX, because EDGE is just showing a blank page.
As the document is ignored completely (due to SOH) try/catch isn't working either...
The error in Firefox displays at least a message containing valuable info as to where the parsing failed:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>
> Location: 127.0.0.1:8080/data/soh.xml
>
> Line Number 4, Column 28:
>
> <mydata> Data with SOH  </mydata>
>
> -----------------------^

Thank you in advance and kind regards :)

*IE11 in v11.3143.14393.0/UpdateV 11.0.140(KB4511872) is working, the newer IE v11.1198.18362.0/UpdateV 11.0.220(KB4586769) shows the same behaviour as Edge.

** Talking about the chromium based EDGE here. (Adjusted after comment of Martin Honnen, thanks)

Comment: Is that about the new, Chromium based Edge? What kind of error do you get in Firefox (FFX?)?

Comment: Yes, it is the chormium baded Edge, Firefox provides at least an error with details. I Updated my Question. Thank you @MartinHonnen

Comment: Both Chrome as well as the Chromium based Microsoft Edge show me an error "xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 1" if I load an XML document containing SOH. As for referencing a stylesheet and getting a blank display, I don't think this is related to the presence of the character, for security reasons or excuses Chrome and Chromium based browsers refuse to apply `xml-stylehseet` referenced XSLT when the XML is loaded over the file system and only show an error "Unsafe attempt to load URL ....xsl" in the error console you can open with F12.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, chrome/chromium based display an error for me as well, but only if i don't reference the stylesheet within the xml, however this is the case within my company. I dont get an Unsafe attempt to load URL in the developer console, I get "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stylesheet/soh.xsl"."
I'll Update my question, as I forgot to mention I am running all this via a local php test server (started via php.exe -S PATH_TO_PROJDIR)

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour for both Chrome and Chromium based Edge when the XML is loaded over HTTP(S). It seems the parse error is not reported if an `xml-stylesheet` pi is present. It might be worth searching the Chrome or Chromium bug data bases, I guess it is a long standing issue which like many XML related stuff they don't care to fix. I don't think, however, there will be a way to have a standards compliant XML 1.0 parser parse your input successfully.

Comment: What seems to work in Chrome or Edge to find out about the error is to pull the XML with the `fetch` function, pass its response body's `text()` to a `DOMParser` and check whether the parsed document has a `parsererror` child.

Comment: Wow, both are good and pretty much appreciated answers, thank you.I will look into the chrome database (but as you, I also doubt that  I will find something helpful).
Regarding the second point, I cant load thr XML via Javascript (at least not for now) As i am not allowed to add new HTML or PHP files. I am only allowed to adjust the current XSL, hence I am not able to use fetch and a designated domparser instance. (If thats what you meant). 
Thank you very much for your answers. Guess I have to talk my superios into it then ;D

Comment: Hey @MartinHonnen,
Just wanted to let you know, that I wasn't able to fix it the way I wanted...
But at least I was allowed to add a cron job on our server, which then removes the control characters from all incoming XML-files.
Thank you for all your help, have a nicee day.